# Why doesn't this regex accept "s 1" type input?

Tags: c++, regex

I have the follwwing regex:
`/([^\s*][\l\u\w\d\s]+) (\d)/`
It should match strings of the form: "some-string digit", e.g. "stackoverflow 1". **Those strings cannot have whitespace at the beginning**.

It works great, **except for the simple strings with one character on the beginning**, e.g.: "s 1". How can I fix it? I am using it in boost::regex (PCRE-compatible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[^\s*]` is eating up your first string character, so when you require one-or-more string characters after it, that'll fail:

```
/([^\s*][\l\u\w\d\s]+) (\d)/
   ^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^     ^^
    "s"   no match      "1"
```

If you fix your misplaced `*`:

```
/([^\s]*[\l\u\w\d\s]+) (\d)/
   ^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^     ^^
   "s";      "s"        "1"
  match
then cancelled
by backtracking
```

But in order to avoid the backtracking, I would instead write the regex like this:

```
/([\l\u\w\d]+[\l\u\w\d\s]*) (\d)/
```

Note that I am only showing the regex itself — re-apply your extra backslashes for use in a C++ string literal as required; e.g.

```
const std::string my_regex = "/([\\l\\u\\w\\d]+[\\l\\u\\w\\d\\s]*) (\\d)/";
```

This can probably be done more optimally anyway (I'm sure most of those character classes are redundant), but this should fix your immediate problem.

You can test your regexes [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html).

Comment: It is supposed to check for whitespace at the beginning of the line.

Comment: No, the `*` in the wrong place is the whole problem.  With it as a qualifier, the parser will backtrack and have it not consume anything, and then find a match.  But as it is, it's looking for exactly one character that is neither space nor an asterisk.

Comment: The `[^\\s*]` part is supposed to check for lines beginning with whitespace. `\s` stands for space in PCRE, see: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax._quot_single_character_quot__character_classes_

Comment: @REACHUS: No need to keep saying what you're trying to do. We get what you're trying to do. Read my answer to find out how to do it successfully.

Comment: @REACHUS, `*` inside square brackets is just literal asterisk. It only has special meaning outside of square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have the `*` in the wrong place: `[^\s*]` matches exactly one character that is neither whitespace nor an asterisk.  (The `s` in `"s 1"` qualifies as "neither whitespace nor an asterisk", so  it is matched and consumed, and no longer available to serve as a match for the next part, `[\l\u\w\d\s]+`. Note that `"s  1"`, with two spaces, would succeed.)

You probably meant `[^\s]*`, which matches any number (including zero) of whitespace characters.   If you make that small change, that will fix your regular expression.

However, there are other improvements to be made.  First, the backslash+letter sequences that are short for character classes can be negated by capitalizing the letter: the character class "everything that's not in `\s`" *can* be written as above, with `[^\s]`, but it can also be written more simply as `\S`.

Next, I don't know what `\l` and `\u` are.  You've tagged this `c++`, so you're presumably using the standard `regex` library, which uses ECMAScript regex syntax.  But the ECMAScript regular expression specification doesn't define those metacharacters.

If you're trying to match "lowercase letters" and "uppercase letters", those are `[:lower:]` and `[:upper:]` - but both sets of letters are already included in `\w`, so you don't need to include them in a character class that also has `\w`.

Pulling those out leaves a character class of `[\w\d\s]` - which is still redundant, because `\w` also includes the digits, so we don't need `\d`.  Removing that, we have  `[\w\s]`, which matches "an underscore, letter, digit, space, tab, formfeed, or linefeed (newline)."

That makes the whole regular expression `\S*[\s\w]+ (\d)`: zero or more non-whitespace characters, followed by at least one whitespace or word character, followed by exactly one space, followed by a digit.  That seems like an unusual set of criteria to me, but it should definitely match "s 1".  And it does, in my testing.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I suppose. The backtracking is the key huh.

Comment: In general, the regex engine will do whatever it takes to find a match. If there is one, it will find it. All those rules about about leftmost, longest, etc. are only there to determine *which* match it finds if there's more than one.

Comment: It still feels unnecessary to rely on a backtracking step. I'd do this differently.

Answer (score -1):

I would expect you could do something like this:

Add 
    {X,} where X is a number, onto the second set of brackets

Like below

```
([^\\s*][\\l\\u\\w\\d\\s]{2,}) (\d)
```

Replace 2 with whatever you want to be your minimum string length.

Comment: But `+` is already equivalent to `{1,}`, and the OP has indicated that he or she wants the minimum string length to be 1. So this answer would appear not to functionally change anything...

Comment: Will this really fix anything?

Comment: Ah, misread it. Whoops!  No, it won't fix it the way you want it to.